# know the different between source and destention in canvas HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I tried the code below from W3S
and they said that blue rect is the source and the red one is  destination one  , and i need to know how did they determined that , is it the order or there is something else??

```
  var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.fillRect(20,20,75,50);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
  ctx.fillStyle="blue";
  ctx.fillRect(50,50,75,50);
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.fillRect(150,20,75,50);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
  ctx.fillStyle="blue";
  ctx.fillRect(180,50,75,50);
```

Comment: what you do draw is the source at the time you draw. what you draw onto is the destination. source becomes destination if you draw later on it, and destination can even become source ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**When using compositing...**

**'destination'** always refers to existing pixels on the canvas.

**'source'** always refers to new pixels that are being added to the canvas.

When source pixels have been drawn to the canvas they become destination pixels.